# Cannot install jenkins slave on a windows machine

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am a very newbie to Jenkins ,

I am trying to Lunch a slave via Java Web Start, and when i try to install the Jenkins slave knowing that the master address is as follow http://masterdomain.com i see that the slave tries to connect to  http://masterdomain.com:54999 , any ideas why this happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins uses a special port for connections between the slave and the master.  By default the port number is variable, but if you have a firewall between the master and the slave you can fix the port number via the URL `<your Jenkins master URL>/configureSecurity/`

Comment: Hi gareth_bowles , thanks for your output here , I understand what you stated , but i would like to put my question differently , my slave is basically trying to connect through port 54999 , but the master is not on that port and so it is failing to connect to the master , is there any config i can change in the slave jar file to change the fact that it is trying to connect through wrong port

Comment: Don't confuse the slave connection port with the HTTP port that you use to access Jenkins through a browser.  If you have the default settings, Jenkins will assign the slave port - it looks like it's picking 54999 for you.  If the slave is failing to connect, you most likely have a firewall blocking port 54999 between the master and the slave.  Post the output from the master and / or slave logs if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey to answer your question from the comments above, the MASTER URL for jenkins is configured in the Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Jenkins Location

The Java Web start tries to get the URL from this location setting and uses it to setup the JNLP Agent on the slave.

Hope this helps.